# how to ignore rerendering on laravel livewire component while typing

Tags: laravel, rendering, livewires, laravel-livewire

i have a wizard form that is a livewire component and it always rerender when i am typing. I want to stop de rerendering until i submit the form.

Who can help me please ?
Sorry for the bad english i'm french.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the `wire:model.defer` attribute instead of `wire:model`.

Comment: the component doesn't rerender while typing but when i click on the next input field it rerenders

Comment: @momo just updated my answer, Livewire v2 introduced `wire:model.defer` which waits until your form has been submitted.